# ios App crash instantly after in-app purchase buying

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, release

Basically, i am in really bad situation. Our team successfully develop and release new version of application with new feature, which users are able to buy (in-app purchases).
So, we have tested all new functionality with iTunes test user, and everything worked great, however, when we saw release version in appStore with real iTunes user, there is a huge problem. User just press button to buy in-app purchase, after he write password of his account and accept to buy this new information. Unfortunately, app crashes everytime after this action. And there is no actions after this.

Basically, for in-app purchases I use MKStoreKit.
So, I would like to present code of the following action:

```
- (IBAction)buyNewRequest:(id)sender
{

id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                                                          action:@"Обработчик нажатия кнопки"
                                                           label:@"Кнопка - отправить запрос. Экран - запроса кредитной истории бки"
                                                           value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]] build]];

if ([self checkValidaionTextFields])
{
    [DejalBezelActivityView activityViewForView:self.view withLabel:@"Подождите..."].showNetworkActivityIndicator = YES;
    self.sendButton.enabled = NO;
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"ru.financemart.nbki"
                                    onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature,
                                                 NSData* purchasedReceipt,
                                                 NSArray* availableDownloads)
     {

         id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
         [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                                                               action:@"Уведомление подтверждения покупки БКИ"
                                                                label:@"Уведомление - покупка бки. Экран - отправки запроса кредитной истории БКИ"
                                                                value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]] build]];

         NSString *stringReceipt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", purchasedReceipt];
         stringReceipt = [stringReceipt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
         stringReceipt = [stringReceipt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
         stringReceipt = [stringReceipt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
         NSString *base64Receipt = [self base64forData:purchasedReceipt];
         NSString *hashDevelopKey = @"i5FnXIZ2aKjdn1Ru2VfLarbdCwbiJvfsnh9QTm9MB0I";
         NSString *hashMD5 = @"";
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:hashDevelopKey];


         NSString *familyText = self.familyTextField.text;
         NSString *nameText = self.nameTextField.text;
         NSString *patronimicText = self.patronimicTextField.text;
         NSString *passportID = self.passportID.text;
         NSString *email = self.emailTextField.text;
         NSString *dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthFormat;
         NSString *passportDate = datePassportFormat;

         NSString *regionForRequest = @"";
         if ([[UnicomAPIConfigResponse lastResponse] cityByID:@(self.unicomProposalsModel.cityID).stringValue].ru_RU != nil) {
             regionForRequest = [[UnicomAPIConfigResponse lastResponse] cityByID:@(self.unicomProposalsModel.cityID).stringValue].ru_RU;
         }

         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:dateOfBirth];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:email];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:nameText];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:patronimicText];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:passportID];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:passportDate];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:base64Receipt];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:regionForRequest];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:familyText];
         NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         NSString *stringToken = [[[[defaults valueForKey:@"deviceToken"] description]
                                   stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                  withString:@""];
         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:stringToken];
         NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
         NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

         hashMD5 = [hashMD5 stringByAppendingString:stringFromDate];

         [DejalBezelActivityView activityViewForView:self.view withLabel:@"Отправляем..."].showNetworkActivityIndicator = YES;



         [self.unicomService postNBKIRequestWithName:nameText WithFamily:familyText andPatronimic:patronimicText andDOB:dateOfBirth andPassport:passportID andPassportDate:passportDate andPartnerName:@"1" andEmail:email andToken:stringToken andReceipt:base64Receipt andHashKey:[self md5:hashMD5] andRegion:regionForRequest success:^(UnicomAPIRequestsNBKIResponse *response)
          {
              self.sendButton.enabled = YES;
          } error:^(NSError *error) {
              self.sendButton.enabled = YES;
              [self performSelector:@selector(showError) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
          }]->addObserver( ^( TLSignal<NSDictionary *> *sender, NSDictionary *response )
                          {
                              [self performSelector:@selector(showSuccessPostRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
                              userModel = [CreditUserModel tlSharedInstance];
                              NSDictionary *dicta = [userModel.serverResponse valueForKey:@"result"];
                              NSString *dictb = [dicta valueForKey:@"id"];
                              NSMutableDictionary *paramNBKI = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:dictb forKey:@"requestID"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:self.familyTextField.text forKey:@"familyName"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:self.patronimicTextField.text forKey:@"patronimic"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:passportID forKey:@"passportID"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:dateOfBirth forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:passportDate forKey:@"passportDate"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:base64Receipt forKey:@"baseReceipt"];
                              [paramNBKI setObject:[self convertDate:[NSDate date]] forKey:@"requestDate"];



                              NSUserDefaults *defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                              if([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"nbkiHistory"])
                              {
                                  NSMutableArray *nbkiHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                  nbkiHistory = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults valueForKey:@"nbkiHistory"]];
                                  [nbkiHistory addObject:paramNBKI];
                                  [defaults setObject:nbkiHistory forKey:@"nbkiHistory"];
                                  NSLog(@"mykey found");
                              } else {
                                  NSMutableArray *nbkiHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                  [nbkiHistory addObject:paramNBKI];
                                  [defaults setObject:nbkiHistory forKey:@"nbkiHistory"];
                              }



                            self.sendButton.enabled = YES;
                          } );
     }
                                   onCancelled:^
     {
         self.sendButton.enabled = YES;
         [DejalBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
     }];

}
}
```

So, after user accept in-app purchase you could see POST request to our server ([self.unicomService postNBKIRequestWithName:), but there are no requests in our server database log, so app crashes before this code. But, there are no code strings where are it is able to crash.

Comment: Can you get a crash dump and see where exactly it happened? You have a lot of code in the completion block and it can crash it few places. For example - what if `[UnicomAPIConfigResponse lastResponse]` is nil? Or `deviceToken` is not saved in the defaults?

Comment: Basically, it is really hard to decode crash log, however we used google analytics and it shows this error, unfortunately, I dont know what does it mean:
"NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: <redacted> <redacted> FinanceMart FinanceMart FinanceMart FinanceMart <redacted> CFArrayApplyFunction <redacted> <re"
Where "FinanceMart - is name of the project.